# Combination of columns, block and center renders the wrong textcolor in the first block

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, columns, block

I just noticed a strange behavior in beamer: if just after the title page, I use a colums environment, in which I put a block, and in which I center the text, the text has the wrong color, namely the title color.

[image]
[image]

ME:

```
\documentclass[9pt,hide notes]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetheme[]{Madrid}
\title{The title}
\author{The Author}


\institute{The University}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{bla}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{bla}
                \begin{center}
                    bla
                \end{center}
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{bla}
                \begin{center}
                    bla
                \end{center}
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: which color you expected? used is default color determined by used theme.

Comment: I do get https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTF2w.png from your MWE. Which engine do you use? Which tex distribution do you have? I vaguely remember a similar bug a while ago, can you try to update?

Comment: I use pdflatex from debian stretch (stable):
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian). What about you?

@zarko: I expect the text color in the first block to be black, as it is in the second one.

Comment: @Geoffroy You'll need texlive2017 for the bug fix.